# Struts Loop breaks at specific number of characters

Tags: java, jsp, struts, loops

I have a jsp which has a struts loop "logic:iterate" which displays all of the delivery basis entries in the database. However, once the loop has output a specific number of characters to the screen, it stops all output and the entire page breaks immediately.

The specific number of characters is evidenced by the fact that removing one character from what the loop outputs each iteration results in the loop outputting what appears as more of the page. For example the current loop looks like this:

```
<logic:iterate name="list" id="item">
    <tr>
        <td><bean:write name="item" property="deliverybasis"/></td>
        <td><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="confirmRemoveDeliveryBasis.do?&id=<bean:write name="item" property="deliverybasis"/>"><bean:message key="text.remove"/></a> </td>
    </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

There are currently 18 rows in the delivery basis table, but the break is happening before the loop can finish. As a result this loop outputs 12 tr's but on the last iteration it only gets as far as the "`<a`" for the removal link. Let's say you remove 1 character from the code, for example deleting 1 character from the href value. By doing this the number of characters output each iteration will decrease by 1. This will make the loop appear as if it outputs more of the code, when in reality it is outputting the exact same amount of characters.

In our example instead of stopping at "`<a`" the loop will stop at '`<a style="text`'. At first glance it would appear as if more characters had been output, but if you remember that we decreased the number of characters output during each iteration by 1, and the fact the there are currently 12 iterations, you realize that the same overall amount of characters has been output. If you notice, ' style="text' is exactly 12 characters.

My question is what could be causing this to happen? Is there a setting or configuration in the code that needs to be set properly?

Comment: Could be anything, not enough to go on. How many characters? What's different about the data in the 12th? Is this on an include? Custom tag? Tile? Of course there's nothing in Struts specifically that would *arbitrarily* stop after *n* characters.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, I found a typo in the form-bean defintion. The form-bean could not find the class I had specified and as a result was having issues. Although in my experience and opinion, this is an odd way for this error to manifest. I would think that it would just break the entire page, not work for half of the page and then quite without any error or notifications.

After fixing this typo, the issue was fixed.

Comment: Should be a message in the startup log.